# Correct way of passing object instance between modules

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, apscheduler, flask-restplus

## SOLVED: Turns out problem comes from gunicorn preloading and forking vs the apscheduler. See comment.

### Background

I am writing a simple flask API that does periodic background query to a SQL database using apscheduler, then serves incoming rest requests with flask. The API will do different aggregation based on the incoming request.

I have a data class object that has methods for 1) querying/updating, 2) responding to aggregation requests. The problem arises when somehow the flask resource seems to be stuck at an older version of the data while the logs show that the query/update method was called properly.

### Code so far

I broke down my app in modules as follow:

```
app/
├── app.py
└── apis
    ├── __init__.py
    └── model1.py
```

### Data model file

In `model1.py`, I defined the data class, the API endpoints with `flask-restplus` namespace, and initialize the data object:

```py
from flask_restplus import Namespace, Resource
import pandas as pd

api = Namespace('sales')

@api.route('/check')
class check_sales(Resource):
    def post(self):
        import json
        req = api.payload
        result = data.get_sales(**req)
        return result, 200

class sales_today():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        # some logging here
        self.data = self.check_sql()
        logging.debug("Last Order: %s" % str(self.data.sales_time.max()))

    def check_sql(self):
        query = """
        SELECT region, store, item, sales_count, MAX(UtcTimeStamp) as sales_time FROM db GROUP BY 1,2,3
        """
        sales = pd.read_gbq(query)
        return sales

    def get_sales(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        kwargs here is a dict where we filter and sum
        '''
        for arg_name in (x for x in kwargs):
            mask = True
            if type(kwargs[arg_name]) is str:
                arg_value = kwargs[arg_name].split(',')
                mask = mask & (self.data[arg_name].isin(arg_value))
        result = {k:v for k,v in kwargs.items()}
        result['count'] = int(self.data.loc[mask]['sales_count'])
        result['last_updated'] = str(self.data.sales_time.max())
        return result

data = sales_today()
```

### Module init file

In `__init__.py` inside `app/apis` I pass the data object instance as well as the api namespace.

```py
from .model1 import api as ns_model1
from .model1 import data as data_model1

def add_apins(api):
    api.add_namespace(ns_model1, path='/model1')
```

### Main app file

In the main `app.py` file I layout the scheduler to keep the data refreshed every 5 minutes with `apscheduler`. I then serve this app with gunicorn.

```
import atexit
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api
from apis import add_apins
from apis import data_model1

# parameters
port = 8888
poll_freq = '0-59/5'

# flask app
main_app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api()
add_apins(api)
api.init_app(main_app)

# background scheduler
sched = BackgroundScheduler()
sched.add_job(data_model1.update, 'cron', minute=poll_freq)
sched.start()
atexit.register(lambda: sched.shutdown(wait=False))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # serve(application, host='0.0.0.0', port=port) # ssl_context="adhoc" for https testing locally
    run_simple(application=main_app, hostname='0.0.0.0', port=port, use_debugger=True)
```

### Expectation and issues

Since the query is updated every 5 minutes, I would expect whenever I query the `/check` endpoint, the responding payload's `last_updated` value will match the latest from the logs (`logging.debug` line in the `update()` method). However, I'm getting responses indicating that the `last_updated` value equals to when the app was run initially.

I have confirmed in the DB that indeed data is up to date there, and from logging, I'm also confirmed that the `update()` method is being run every 5 minutes and showing the latest timestamp.

I also noticed that the app runs fine with `python app.py` in Windows, but when running the app with *gunicorn* it starts exhibiting this weird behaviour.

I am quite puzzled as to where things go wrong. Could it be scoping? Or am I passing the instance between modules wrongly?

Thank you so much for your time and help. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a gunicorn issue and how the app is being called. Apparently I have been running the app with preload option, which causes forking of the app after the data and scheduler is initialized, which means that the update() method is not updating the actual data that's being used while serving traffic through flask. Testing now to see if this is indeed completely the reason.

Comment: App was run using:
`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8888 --preload app:main_app`

Comment: Alright tests confirmed that it is indeed preload that is causing trouble, not the code itself.